# GKMatch sendData generates EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT and EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, game-center

I am migrating my game to Swift. When I reach the point where the game should send massages to the other player via Game Center, I am receiving EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT error on my iPhone 5 and getting an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error on the iOS simulator.

myMatch is initialized from the GameCenterViewController. Everything seems to be fine, but whatever I do I get this failures and the program crashes.

I have tried to call the sendDataToAllPlayers. Result is the same. Trying nil for the error, same failure. Trying empty message, same failure.

My code is below:

```
   func StartOnlineGame() {
    PlayedNumberSent=false
    caller=0

    self.playerReset()
    myMatch.delegate=self;
    gameState=Game_States.GAME_RUNNING

    myCoin=Int(arc4random())

    var init_message:network_message = network_message(message:messagetype.M_INIT, playercoin: 0)
    var messageData:NSData?
    var error: NSError?

    init_message.playercoin=myCoin;

    //var toPlayers=myMatch.players

    messageData!=NSData(bytes:&init_message, length:sizeof(network_message))
    myMatch.sendData(messageData!, toPlayers:myMatch.players, withDataMode:GKMatchSendDataMode.Reliable, error:&error)

}
```

Thanks for any help!

```
Endre
```

Comment: I am *really* looking forward to a game that can send massages to other players! ;-)

Comment: Hi, They need to send messages. :) But really, this is annoying issue as I cannot find what is causing it. I think the message data formed wrongly maybe, but absolutely not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it turned out that this was a bug in the Swift compiler. It could not be fixed with any code update.

I had to go back to Objective-C until all these bugs are fixed.